# UIViewController with multiple UIPickerViews and arrays

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get two `UITextFields` to show a `UIPickerView` with different arrays when pressed.

Currently, I have the following UIPickerView show the array `pickOption` when `pickerTextField` is pressed.

How can I have my TextField `pickerTextField2` show the array `pickOptions2` when pressed, all on the same `UIViewController`.

I understand I have to

**Code So far:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField2: UITextField!


    var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    var pickOption2 = ["two", "four", "six", "eight", "ten"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()

        pickerView.delegate = self

        pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickOption.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickOption[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerTextField.text = pickOption[row]
    }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068404/multiple-uipickerview-in-one-viewcontroller

Comment: Add a tap gesture to the text field you are referring to such that the user is supposed to tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign tag to your IBOutlet TextField and also take one more textfield variable for assigning current selected textfield.

I Write example here based on your code.Using this logic you can implement picker view functionality with many more textfield.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField2: UITextField!

    var textField1: UITextField?
    var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    var pickOption2 = ["two", "four", "six", "eight", "ten"]

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField1 = textField
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerTextField.delegate = self
        pickerTextField2.delegate = self
        pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
        pickerTextField2.inputView = pickerView
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
           return pickOption.count
        }
        return pickOption2.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            return pickOption[row]
        }
        return pickOption2[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            textField1?.text = pickOption[row]
            return
        }
        textField1?.text = pickOption2[row]
    }
}
```